# What am I missing with my pod install? Xcode Build fails Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, cocoapods, azure-pipelines

I am using an Azure Devops Build pipeline to build my Xcode workspace. It builds fine locally as well as if I import the repo and use it in AppCenter to build.
But I want to use an external Git, thus using a Build Pipeline.

It is pretty simple in terms of steps.

1 - Get Repo (finishes this step)

2 - Pod Install (finishes this step)

3 - Install Cert/Provision Profile (finishes this step)

4 - Build

Here is the yaml for pod

```
steps: task: CocoaPods@0 displayName: 'pod install'
```

And result from the task:

```
Pod installation complete! There are 9 dependencies from the Podfile and 9 total pods installed.
```

**AND HERE IS THE ERROR**

▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'

❌  /Users/vsts/agent/2.149.1/work/1/s/MyDemo/Extension Files/SortedArray.swift:10:8: no such module 'Starscream'

import Starscream

```
   ^
```

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

(2 failures)

### [error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

I have looked through the docs and I can't figure out what is going on. I've messed with the settings to no avail.

Using Xcode 10 to build.

Thanks

Comment: I am having this same issue with MaterialComponents

Comment: @K2SO Ghost Spirit If possible can you please share azure-pipelines.yml file ? I am stuck cocoa pod installation step

Comment: @AsifBanarasDhamial Have you found any solutions for cocoa pod installation? If yes, please help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/72725563/11675817

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error is due to the Xcode task not working out of the workspace path.

Update the `xcWorkspacePath` variable in your `azure-pipelines.yml` file from `**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace` to `yourProjectName.xcworkspace`.

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: 'yourProjectName.xcworkspace'
```

Comment: this does not help in my case, do you have any other solution?